# Merging projects under one solution with single exe file

Tags: vb.net

I have various small apps which I would like to to gather under a new application where they can all be accessed from one "exe" file. I have merged the projects into a solution called "ETABS SUIT" and referenced the projects.

I was expecting and hoping to have just one executable file in the debug folder when I build the solution, but it seems like all projects are built separately with standalone exe files.

[image: Solution with different projects]

Is there a different way to combine all my projects under a new solution and get a single exe file when built? (It may be also okay if I can check a boolean value provided in the main solution before starting the other projects but what I define in the main solution is not recognized in added projects)

Comment: No there isn't. Each project creates its own output. A solution is simply a container for multiple projects. You could build each of those projects as a library instead of an application, then create a single application that references each library project and exposes the functionality they provide.